# Android Auto - how to show icons instead of text in root menu

Tags: java, android, android-mediasession

I'm working on an android auto media app and want to structure the root menu with icons instead of text.
Like in the documentation see [here](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media#root-menu-structure).
How can I achieve this? My example below converts an png from drawable into bitmap.
The tabs of root menu remain black.

I got the same result, using an `uri` instead of bitmap.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getInstance().getResources(), R.drawable.recently_played);
MediaDescriptionCompat desc =
     new MediaDescriptionCompat.Builder()
          .setMediaId(HEADER)
          .setIconBitmap(bitmap)
          .build();
```

How can I place an drawable as icon in root menu of android auto?

Many Thanks,
Alejandro

Comment: Did you keep reading down that page where it talks about [applying a grid content style](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media#apply_content_style)?

Comment: Of course, but I want the icons in the header. Like Home, Recently, Browse.